Django Webhook Integration with Aiogram
Overview
This project integrates a Telegram bot (using Aiogram) with a Django application via a webhook. However, when running python manage.py migrate, the following error occurs:
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Unclosed client session

Issue

The error suggests issues with the event loop being closed prematurely and an unclosed aiohttp client session.
The webhook handler processes updates from Telegram asynchronously using Aiogram, but the event loop is not managed properly in Django’s synchronous views.

Code
session = AiohttpSession()
bot = Bot(token=settings.BOT_TOKEN, session=session, default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML))
dp = Dispatcher()

@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            update_data = json.loads(request.body)
            update = Update(**update_data)

            async def process_update():
                await dp.feed_update(bot=bot, update=update)

            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            if loop.is_closed():
                loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
                asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
            loop.run_until_complete(process_update())

            return HttpResponse("OK")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error: {e}")
            return HttpResponse("Bad Request", status=400)
    return HttpResponse("Method not allowed", status=405)

ask for ChatGPT but without success.

Shouldn't you use an async view?  Also, I'd recommend moving process_update to the module scope.  It's a bit confusing having nested functions.

I recommend pytelegrambotapi for use with django, django works synchronously while aiogram works asynchronously so there may be problems when using it together.
You can read more on the Russian blog below:  https://habr.com/ru/articles/679362/
